# modal window in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have to write a web page which contains a form with at least 5 input fields and a button. If the user clicks on that button a modal interface window (actually a div) should pop out in the center of the browser window. This modal window should contain 4 input fields and a button. If the user clicks on that button, the modal window disappears and all the values inserted by the user in the modal window's input fields will be concatenated and added to a text field in the main form. During the time the modal window is displayed, the fields from the main form will be inactive and a transparrent gray div should be displayed on top of the web page (this grey div should be beneath the modal window and should occupy the whole browser window).

I know how to work with jQuery, but my problem is that I do not know how to open an close that modal window.

Comment: Please share whatever code you've written first.

Comment: It's a div, all you need to do is call jQuery's `.show()` on it. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Yes, but how can you show it on button click and close it when clicking Submit? And I don't know this part mainly: fields from the main form will be inactive and a transparrent gray div should be displayed on top of the web page

Comment: Call `.on('click', ...)` on the button to assign a click handler. Call `.on('submit', ...)` on the modal's form to assign a submission handler. Call `.attr('disabled', ...)` on the fields. I don't mean to be rude, but when you say "I know how to work with jQuery", what exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML has one built in. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

```js
function openModal(){
  document.querySelector('#myModal').showModal()
}
function closeModal(){
  document.querySelector('#myModal').close();
  let values = [...document.querySelector('#myModal').querySelectorAll('input')].map(e=>e.value).join(', ');
  document.querySelector('#values').innerHTML = values;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit atem... </p>
<div id="values"></div>
<button onclick="openModal()">open modal</button>

<dialog id="myModal">
  <button onclick="closeModal()">close</button>

  <h2>Hi I am a dialog!</h2>
  Input 1
  <input type="text" ><br>
  Input 2
  <input type="text" ><br>
  Input 3
  <input type="text" ><br>
  Input 4
  <input type="text" ><br>
  Input 5
  <input type="text" ><br>
</dialog>
```

Comment: This is not a jQuery solution and not supported in all major browsers yet.